# How do I store output of a git command in a Perl array or scalar?

Tags: arrays, git, perl

In my code I have

```
git diff --numstat
```

I know I could create a file with

```
git diff --numstat > log.log
```

But is it even possible to pass this into an array or scalar of some sort? I was thinking something like this but I'm not sure why it doesn’t compile.

```
my @array;
push (@array, git diff --numstat);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use backticks, also known more generally as [qx//](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#qx%2f_STRING_%2f):

> - `qx/STRING/`
> - `` `STRING` ``
>     A string which is (possibly) interpolated and then executed as a system command with `/bin/sh` or its equivalent. Shell wildcards, pipes, and redirections will be honored. The collected standard output of the command is returned; standard error is unaffected. In scalar context, it comes back as a single (potentially multi-line) string, or [`undef`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/undef.html) if the command failed. In list context, returns a list of lines (however you've defined lines with [`$/`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR) or [`$INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR)), or an empty list if the command failed.

You have options, and which is better depends on what you want to do with the output.

To read all of the standard output into a scalar, use the operator in scalar context as in

```
$output = `git diff --numstat`;
```

In list context with the default value of `$/`, perl splits the output into separate lines. If you want to append the `git` output to the end of an existing array, use [`push`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/push.html), as in

```
push @array, `git diff --numstat`;
```

Although you mentioned `push` specifically in your question, I’m having a hard time imagining why you’d mix the output of `git` with something else. Storing the output in an array directly is simpler:

```
@array = `git diff --numstat`;
```

Note that the list of lines returned retain their end-of-line characters. To create a new array and remove all of the newlines in one line, write

```
chomp(@array = `git diff --numstat`);
```

or even

```
chomp(my @array = `git diff --numstat`);
```

if you’re running under [`use strict`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html).

#### Error Handling

For code that you plan to use more than once or twice, you should check that `` `git diff --numstat` ``, or any other command whose output you want to read, actually succeeded. Otherwise, with the [`warnings`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) pragma enabled, you’ll see lots of diagnostic messages about undefined variables or missing output.

In scalar context, failure will return the undefined value. Check it as in

```
my $output = `git diff --numstat`;
die "$0: git may not be installed" unless defined $output;
```

Failure in list context produces an empty list.

```
my @output = `git diff --numstat`;
die "$0: git may not be installed" unless @output;
```